# How to create dynamic images in Crm 2011 on-premise

Tags: html, silverlight, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I want guidance as well as help here. I am creating a customization where an entity is supposed to have dynamic images. Its an image of a floor and when I click on the floor, it should open up to show me an image of floor wings and from floor wings to rooms in the wings and from there to particular rooms. The rooms should have indicators showing whether the bed in the room is empty or occupied (e.g red for occupied and green for empty). These indicators are the one that needs to be updated based on values in a form.

I am absolutely lost on how to proceed on this and even if it can be achieved in CRM or not. My little knowledge tells me that it can be done either by silverlight or by html5. Any guidance and help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have already created entities/relationships for Floors/Floor Wings, Rooms, Bed etc.

Attach the correct floorplan image to each of these entity records.

You'll probably need to store image maps (additional entity maybe?) along with the images so that the user can generate events by clicking on different parts of the floor plan image.

You can then build an html page that uses the odata service and Javascript to display the correct image based on the user's interaction with the page. Implement the logic to transition to the correct part of the floor plan based on the information pulled using the ODATA service.

Then display this HTML page in an IFRAME on the entity.

Should be fun to implement, let me know how it goes.

Comment: i will surely can back to you after a little more R&D. Do stay in touch Sunil

Comment: And do I really need different entities for floors/wings/rooms? Cant I have one entity with all these as fields in a form?

and what do you mean by image maps?

Comment: Check here for info in the html <map> tag.http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: You could have one single entity but I think logically it would make more sense if you modeled them separately. Feel free to mark my response as an answer if it helped :)

Comment: It did help to help me get started so here you go. Thank you